# When disconnecting socket, waiting time occurs

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2013, asyncsocket

I'm studying network and Windows forms with C# these days.

I'm trying to build an async-socket network system, everything's working well.

codes for Connect and Connect Callback are below.

```
 private void ClientConnect()
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        try
        {
            socket.BeginConnect(endPoint, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), socket);

            connectDone.WaitOne();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Send(socket, textBox3.Text, 0);

            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But in disconnecting socket, there's a problem.

I make a button to disconnect socket, and codes for button-clicked event are below.

```
private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            Application.DoEvents();
            socket.Disconnect(true);    //-> problem occurs.
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Disconnect Error!");
        }

        if (socket.Connected)
            MessageBox.Show("Disconnect Error!");
        else
            textBox1.AppendText("Disconnected! (" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ")\n");
    }
```

When I disconnect the socket, 2 minutes of waiting time occurs.

after 2 minute(I checked this with time-stamp), It shows 'Disconnected' message.

And I can re-connect with this socket.

I think it is not just waiting like sleep, something's processed in background.

(Because mouse cursor's changed and program's blocked)

I'm so wondering why this delay(?) happens.

Please let me know.

Comment: If you want to learn how to do it right, drop `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` and `Application.DoEvents();`. Those are workarounds.

Comment: You need to read about socket programming. A correct "graceful closure" involves the initiator of the disconnect using shutdown(send) only, and then waiting until a receive operation completes with a 0 byte count. Then the disconnect will happen promptly (assuming the remote endpoint is written correctly). The way you're doing it, the socket gets stuck in a wait state designed to ensure against data loss/corruption. When the disconnect is done correctly, no such errors are possible and the closure can be done promptly.

Comment: @Peter Duniho So you mean I have to change Shutdown(both) to Shutdown(send)? But I want to add function for receiving message. And.. I  discard some synchronizations(waitone/set), Still waiting occurs. Is there any possibility that server program has problem with this?

Comment: _"I have to change Shutdown(both) to Shutdown(send)?"_ -- yes, that's what I mean. But that alone won't fix your problem. You still need to correctly handle the remote endpoint also shutting the socket down (which you detect by seeing a receive operation complete with a byte count of 0). _" Is there any possibility that server program has problem with this?" -- sorry, it is unclear what you mean by "this". But assuming a correctly written server, then when your client code is also written correctly, it will work fine. No problems.